# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 when exporting individual excel row to JSON file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a spreadsheet with 100 rows for example, and want to export each row to an individual JSON file named <the row number>.json.
However I get this error and am not sure what I could be doing wrong.
Code is as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from pandas import read_excel


root_location = Path("/fullpath/")
df = pd.read_excel("/fullpath/toexcelfile.xlsx") 
rowNumber = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    with open(root_location / (str([rowNumber]) + ".json"), "w") as f:
        f.write(str(row[rowNumber]))
        rowNumber +=1
```

Thank you so much for your help.

EDIT:

I have tried

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from pandas import read_excel

df = pd.read_excel("/fullpath/excel.xlsx", index=[0, 1], columns=['A']) 

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    with open((str([index]) + ".json"), "w") as f:
        f.write(row.to_string(row))
```

Which is now giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'
```

Comment: I don't know content of the `xlsx` file but I think you should remove this line: `rowNumber +=1` and everything will work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an index out of the bounds of the array `row` in the `f.write(str(row[rowNumber]))` line, where you're trying to access the index `rowNumber` of `row`.

You have already the row in your `for` and with `row[rowNumber]` you are not accessing the `rowNumber`-th row, but the `rowNumber`-th element of the current row and this, if the data are not properly formatted, could lead to an index out of bounds as we saw.

In summary, on each iteration of the `for` you were accessing the element `row[rowNumber]` but each time incrementing both `row` and `rowNumber` by 1; by this we can say that the program would only consider the values of the diagonal of the `dataframe` (i.e. [0,0],[1,1],... ,[n,n]).

Since you have to export each single row, you can do something similar to the simplified example below, using only the `row` given from `iterrows()`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame((['Value0', 'Value1'],['Value2', 'Value3']), index=[0, 1], columns=['A', 'B'])
#   |    A   |    B   |
# 0 | Value0 | Value1 |
# 1 | Value2 | Value3 |

for column, row in df.iterrows():
    with open((str([column]) + ".txt"), "w") as f:
        f.write(str(row))
```

Output:

[0].txt

```
A    Value0
B    Value1
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

[1].txt

```
A    Value2
B    Value3
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

**Edit for the updated question**:

You've got a `TypeError` because `read_excel()` doesn't accept the same arguments as the constructor `DataFrame()`. To handle this, you'll need to read the excel file and formatting the `dataframe` in base of your needs. Since I don't know the exact formatting of that file, I can't provide an exact solution. The best I can do is to refer you [to the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) which explain each and every argument of the matter.

Besides, just a hint, I suggest you to print a dummy `dataframe` as an example of the actual one, in order to better understand how to correctly approach it

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly!  One question, how can I remove the following extra info at the end of the files: NaN
Name: 24999, dtype: object.   I rally appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm happy to help. To get the format that you want, you can simply use the `.to_string()` method on `row` as it follows: `f.write(row.to_string())`. Also, if you want to remove the indexes (`A` and `B`) you can specify it in this method, `row.to_string(index=False)`.

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon, it has generated more text files than rows, and has only given the the first rows data, but its close.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) is the documentation about the `DataFrame.to_string()` method, if you want to know more

Comment: Actually it might be that I forgot to add the index info.  I am gonna play around and then do an edit.  I really appreciate your help, and you have a very clear explanation.

Comment: Thanks again for yur help, I made an edit in my post with the latest code that incorporates your feedback.  Is there anything you can see that looks out of place?